# Django: Heroku buildpacks error?

Tags: python, django, heroku

My Django App is being rejected by Heroku.

It says: App not compatible with buildpack. And gives a url for more info.

After visiting this URL and applying the "solution":

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

The problem continues. Had you similar problems?

This is my app (just Django):

https://github.com/OmarGonD/direlim27

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

These are my files after Heroku preparation (with Procfile, etc).

[image]

Comment: it seems that you don't have a Procfile, no requirements.txt and no runtime.txt and you do not use a Postgres DB. And BTW nice Secret_Key you got there. I suggest to follow the Deploy on heroku with Django documentation written b heroku

Comment: There is a Procfile in my local directory. The github app is just pure Django, without any Heroku preparation. See edit 1. What secret key are you talking about?